How to opt out of AI search?
I noticed that any search has a new feature now, of automated GenAI response, e.g. when searching for how to opt out of AI search? I got this:



How to get rid or opt out of the part in red circle, i.e. the AI response?

It's annoying not only because the results are typically bad, but also because the processing takes a few seconds and a animation is shown (which is distracting), and during that time it says "Processing request" (I didn't request AI-based output, just a normal search)

I like it. As long as it quotes the actual answer verbatim, I am happy for such results

@Dharman well, I disagree, but there's no downvotes for comments to show it.

Additionally, sites themselves should be able to opt out entirely. It is harmful on spoiler-heavy sites like Puzzling.

Closing this one as I've answered the more direct question of "was the test officially announced". But yeah, should've never happened :)

As a temporary solution, you can add the following rule to an ad blocker like uBlock Origin:
###search-summary

As the saying goes,

Nothing is so permanent as a temporary solution.

